# Hypersphere - Pattern matching using Centroid, Radius and Diameter

Tags: computational-geometry, pattern-recognition, tessellations

I have a hyper-sphere formed with set of $n$-dimensional data points. I could calculate centroid ($X_0$), radius($R$) and diameter($D$).

Using these $X_0, R, D$, how I can find whether the a given data point falls within the boundary or outside.

Would like to know if any other measure caters this use-case.

Comment: Currently experimenting with a data set using insights from the below posts

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/102545/how-do-i-calculate-the-unique-k-dimensional-hyperspheres-center-from-k1-points
http://www.oocities.org/kiranisingh/center.html

Any help much appreciated

Comment: "Would like to know if any other measure caters this use-case." No idea what you mean.

Comment: A point is on the hypersphere if and only its distance to the center equals the radius. If you want to know something beyond this simple fact, you should be more specific about what you want and how you define $X_0$, $R$ and $D$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implicit equation of an hypersphere is

$$(x-x_o)^2+(y-y_o)^2+\dots(t-t_o)^2=r^2.$$

Inside the hypersphere, $LHS<RHS$ and conversely outside.

Comment: Thanyou. You mean X0 = (X1+X2+x3.....+Xn)/N? similarly Y0? This condition is not working even I with the data point from the original dataset. Not sure where it is going wrong.

Comment: Let me give more details, 
2D Data set is: (10,100), (9,101), (11,99), (12,98), (9,100), (10,101), (9,101), (11,99), (12,98), (9,100), (10,100), (9,101), (11,99), (12,98), (9,100), (10,101), (9,101), (11,99), (12,98), (9,100), (25,300), (24,301), (26,298)
X0: (12.13043478, 125.7826087).
Radius(r): 323.
Centre euclidean distance of the data point (26, 298) is 183. Is that means the point is inside the hyper-sphere?

Comment: @NageswaraRao: of course. What is "not working" ?

Comment: The problem I am facing, the boundary is too high to accommodate points much beyond. For example (30,350) which is outside theoretically. By equation, centre euclidean distance of the point (235) is lesser than radius 323, that shows point is inside which is wrong practically. I am not a core math scholar, sorry if I am missing something. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: "which is outside theoretically / which is wrong practically": what do you mean ?

Comment: I meant, the data point (30,350) is not part of my initial data set which is used to define the properties of hyper-sphere. I expect same thing while comparing distance with radius.

Comment: What prevents it from being inside the sphere ?

Comment: I am not sure how that can be inside. I am looking for a formula constituting Centroid, radius and diameter, on applying should say the data points ranging (1-25, 98-125) belongs to hypersphere, rest out side... Thanks for your patience

Comment: Please refer me any material which I can go through... if you can

Comment: Plot your points, take a pair of compasses and draw the circle by the computed point with computed radius.

Comment: Fantastic.. Thanks for your input. I have found the upper boundary as follows.. 1. Calculated radius of each point towards centroid (R1, R2, ..... Rn) 2. Took average radius (R0) 3. Found standard deviation of radius i.e, SDR = SQRT(SUM((Rn-R0)^2)/n) 4. Upper limit = R0+3SDR. Distance measure of all the points falls within the boundary. I did it everything manually using MSEXCELL. Would like to know if there is formula for calculating average radius and SD. Again thanks for your inputs

Comment: I could crack formula to calculate average radius and Average Pair wise distance  [(1/N*(N-1))*∑∑(Xi - Xj)^2]^1/2. But wanted to know if Average Pair wise distance (D) can be taken as in place of variance. So that I can apply SD=SQRT((D^2)/N). Any help much appreciated

Comment: Aren't you looking for the tightest bounding sphere ?

Comment: Not really, I am looking for maximum extent I can stretch the boundary to fit all the points. Ideally the measure is Mean+3SD which can cover 99.9% of my points.